# Join only if a value is equal to 1

Tags: sql

Hey so I have a question that I am surprised I cannot easily find an answer for. Basically I am trying to join a table only and only if a value is equal to 1. I have tried using case statements but this won't work so I am at an impasse and would greatly appreciate a few suggestions.

Basically I have a passed table @courseSection and a local variable @isSelect all = 0. So now I want to check is a -1 in the @courseSection table.

Pseudo code:

```
       If @courseSection contains -1 then
       @isSelectAll = 1
       end

       if @isSelect all = 1 then
       inner join course s on c.id = cs.id
       end
```

This is all inside a Select statement too. Has anyone a suggestion on how to accomplish this and thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You could include it in your `ON` in some fashion - `INNER JOIN course s ON c.id = cs.id AND @isSelectAll = 1`. That being said, you may have to then change the join to a `LEFT JOIN` with an `IS NOT NULL`, as your `INNER JOIN` will find 0 records when `@isSelectAll <> 1`.

Comment: Oracle? MS-SQL? MYSQL? need more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Dynamic query, you cannot `Join` tables based on `CASE` evaluation.

```
Declare @sql varchar(max)= ''

Set @sql = 'your current query without join'

Set @sql  += case when @isSelect all = 1 then ' inner join course s on c.id = cs.id ' 
             else '' end

--print @sql
Exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to do the join sometimes, then you must not be using any of those columns from the joined table, and are doing the join only as a filter - otherwise it doesn't make sense.

If that was the case, then instead of a `join`, do an `in` or `exists`:

```
select * from MyTable
where (@isSelectall <> 1 or id in (select id from course))
```

If you are actually using some of the columns from `course`, then you'd have to do the `left join` from the comment, or dynamic SQL like the other answer.